# How to access the height and width of path element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have an svg path element. I want to access the height, width, x and y of the path element and after changing it want to set it back

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
</svg>
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the bounding box by calling `getBBox()` so give the path an id attribute e.g. id="path1" and then in a script write

```
var bbox = document.getElementById("path1").getBBox();
```

bbox will have x, y, width and height attributes but you can't change them directly.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am a fan of livesnippets:

```js
var bbox = document.getElementById("path1").getBBox();

console.log(bbox);
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" id="path1"/>
</svg>
```